# Enemies are Everywhere I Look!

Tags: riddle, knowledge, wordplay, video-games

A last hurrah for the video game challenge:

> Well here I am, on the run from the mob.  Lin Hyle, that’s the pork-peahatted big boss that I’ve done wrong.  Like, like I don’t really know what I did to burst his bubble.  Sure, if I had the time I could puzzle it out, but doesn’t even matter.
>
> I had to ditch my beetle about a mile back; the shift lever jammed    into park after I hit a hole, and I skidded into a tree.  Jumping out, I could see even in the dark, nuts missing from my wheels.  It had been a setup.
>
> I grabbed my keys and some rope from the trunk and took off into the depths of the woods.  In the distance I hear a train sounding its lonesome “choo….choo…”.  But every sound seems to scare me at this point, and every*thing*, too.  It feels like enemies are all around, and I know the power and the… the thoroughness of Lin: he doesn’t just make you dead, he makes you redead.

Who am I? And why do I feel surrounded by my foes?

Comment: Is that supposed to be "pork _pie_ hatted big boss?"

Comment: @APrough If you are asking me, then yes, that is correct.  But if you are asking the character in the riddle, then no, not necessarily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are

> Link, from the Legend of Zelda series

Reasons

> "Peahat", "Darknut" and "Redead" are mentioned in the puzzle (as well as numerous other creatures, as Zymus points out), and they are enemies from the Zelda games.  "Lin Hyle" is awfully close to "Link Hylian", "time" is mentioned in the first paragraph as well as "puzzle".  In addition, grabbing "keys" from a "trunk" is a fairly rampant past-time in Zelda games.

Comment: Like Like's as well

Comment: @APrough You got it.  Hopefully it wasn't easy as pie.  As you and Zymus have noted, there's quite  a few allusions, but it all came from the inspiration of darknuts being lug nuts.  Nice work!

Comment: Also "moblin", "bubble", "lever", and "chuchu".